# How to extract the line containg Duration only?

Tags: bash, grep, stderr, io-redirection, ffprobe

I want to extract the line `Duration: 00:03:51.05, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 131 kb/s` from output of `ffprobe test.mp3`.

```
ffprobe  test.mp3  |grep  Duration
```

All lines were output with my desired line, how to output my desired line only?

Comment: This might help: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `|` by `2>&1 |` to redirect stderr to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

ffprobe  test.mp3  2>&1 |  awk -F'[ ,]'  '/Duration/{print $4}'
00:03:51.05